# What are valid contents of the "address_from" field? Is it context sensitive?

Tags: shippo

In various places in the API documentation, I see where I can pass a JSON object with address information:

https://goshippo.com/docs/first-shipment

or using an address identifier:

https://goshippo.com/docs/manifests

Can I use either JSON or an identifier for the address_from field anytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the address object_id in place of the full address object for any `address_to` or `address_from` field.

You can see at https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#shipments-create that you can provide either a `string` or an `object` to create the shipment.

Comment: It would be really helpful if the docs were updated to say that.  Thank you very much for quick help!